# Как извлечь файлы HTML, CSS, JS из сайта на wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, cms

У меня есть доступ к хостингу, на котором лежит сайт на wordpress, надо извлечь из него HTML, CSS, JS файлы как бы по отдельности, дабы их отредактировать и перезалить как сайт без CMS, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Идешь сюда: `адрес домена\wp-content\themes\нужная тема\ `     
 
   Стили будут лежать в корне, остальное интуитивно смотри по шаблонам и каталогам.... загляни в файл   `functions.php`  , посмотри какие скрипты и откуда грузятся....

Comment: Проще будет через [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) зеркало сделать и править статические файлы.

Comment: в wp-content\themes\ лежит 4 темы, и во всех все файлы имеют расширение .php и ни одного .html

Comment: А ты что ожидал там увидеть? Читай ниже как посмотреть с генерированный html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте ваш сайт + правой стороной мыши вызовите диалоговое окно + выберите и нажмите Просмотреть исходный код. В открывшемся исходном коде выберите линк файла, который вам требуется + нажмите на этот линк + откроется код файла - скопируйте этот код и перенесите в вашу среду разработки (например NotePad) и запомните как .. в вашем компьютере. Так вы можете создать на вашем компе все файлы. Для ХТМЛ кода просто скопируйте исходный код страницы и перенесите это в вашу среду разработки.